# Console Utility that can remote connect to other systems and issue commands

Tags: powershell-2.0

Frequenlty my work involves to VNC to a remote system and work on it. SInce i run command line apps on this remote system most of the time, i was wondering if there's an alternative software to command prompt which i could install on my local machine. Using this i should be able to create a session with the remote system and from then on all commands issued in command prompt should run in remote system.

localHost>dir --> should list the directory contents in remotehost active directory

localhost>app.exe should run app.exe in remote host and display its contents in localhost command prompt

I browsed a little and read about cmdlets in powershell. But it looks like i need to write a cmdlet for each app in the path (dir, mkdir, app.exe in the path). Correct me if am wrong. Once session is established, i simply need the commands invoked in local host to be run in the remote host  and return the console output to local host. Please let me know if powershell + cmdlets are the only way

THanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use PowerShell Remoting if it can be set up (requires a little preparation).

I'm not quite sure why you think of writing own cmdlets for stuff that's already there. `dir` is an alias to `Get-ChildItem` which does return the items in the current path (and—depending on options—some other stuff as well). And since PowerShell is a shell it has no problems running external programs too.

Answer (score 0):

SSH is what you're looking for.  [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com) has a SSH server and client.

Answer (score 0):

Unix people do this all the time with SSH. You can install the [sshd](http://www.noah.org/ssh/cygwin-sshd.html) server on your remote machine through Cygwin, then use [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) to connect to it.

As a bonus, PuTTY does not use the clunky Windows `cmd.exe` program; it's got a much nicer terminal of its own.

You could maybe even run PowerShell on the remote end, so you don't have to learn bash.

Comment: `cmd.exe` has nothing to do with the Windows console capabilities. None of the two does terminal emulation because, well, Windows is not UNIX. Still, in your analogy the UNIX shell would do the terminal emulation stuff instead of the terminal. Which is ... not the case.

Comment: I thought `cmd.exe` sort-of did both. So who's the Windows terminal then?

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon on how you actuall access the machines [PSExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) may be an alternative that wont require you to install anything on the remote system.